# Angular 7 : Select tag doesn't display options

Tags: html, angular

I created a simple blog application using angular 7.In the create component of the application the user has to fill up some details in a form to create a blog.The select tag is not displaying any options.

Below is the html code of the component:

```
<div class="form-group">
      <label>Category</label>
      <select [(ngModel)]="blogCategory" #category="ngModel" name="blogCategory" class="form-control" id="category" required>
            <option *ngFor="let category of possibleCategories" [value]="category">{{category}}</option>
          </select>
    </div>
```

Below is the typescript file of the component:

```
 public blogTitle : string;
  public blogBodyHtml: string;
  public blogDescription : string;
  public blogCategory : string;
  public possibleCategories :["Comedy","Action","Drama","Technology"];



  ngOnInit() {
  }

  public createBlog():any{
    let blogData= {
      title: this.blogTitle,
      description:this.blogDescription,
      blogBody:this.blogBodyHtml,
      category:this.blogCategory
    }
    console.log(blogData);

    this.blogHttpService.createBlog(blogData).subscribe(

      data =>{
        console.log("Blog created");
        console.log(data);

        this.toastr.success('Blog posted successfully', 'Success');
        setTimeout(()=>{
          this.router.navigate(['/blog',data.data.blogId]);
        },5000)
      },

      error =>{
        console.log("error ocurred");
        console.log(error.errorMessage);

        this.toastr.error('Error occured','Error');

      }
    )
  }
```

Here is the screenshot:
[select not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vLst.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2):

**You have not initialised possibleCategories**

This line:

```
possibleCategories :["Comedy","Action","Drama","Technology"];
```

is declaring a variable, named `possibleCategories`, the **type** of the variable is an array of the four specific strings listed, but the **value** is `null`.

Change that line to read

```
possibleCategories = ['Comedy','Action','Drama','Technology'];
```

and you should have more success.

Note that you don't have to specify a type as TypeScript is able to ascertain the type from the assignment. You would only have to specify a type if the array might otherwise contain values that aren't strings, in which case you might for example declare and initialise as

```
possibleCategories: (string|number)[] = ['Comedy','Action','Drama','Technology'];
```

or

```
possibleCategories: any[] = ['Comedy','Action','Drama','Technology'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change line

```
public possibleCategories :["Comedy","Action","Drama","Technology"];
```

to

```
public possibleCategories: any  = ["Comedy","Action","Drama","Technology"];
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because your `possibleCategories` is **not initialized**. You are defining the type of `possibleCategories` not assigning a value to it. So when `select` is being rendered on page, it doesn't find any options to loop through and display.

You should assign value to `possibleCategories`:

```
public possibleCategories: Array<string>  = ["Comedy","Action","Drama","Technology"];
```